# How to use JWT with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, angular, jwt

I finished my designs for the login and signup pages of my app. I am trying to learn how to use JWT library along with PHP and MySQL database to keep a user logged in or assure that he is allowed to take actions in the app. I see that some people use it with firebase.

I searched a lot but can't find how to start.

I am using angular 2 as frontend.

Comment: You can learn more about JWT here: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: I need it in PHP

Comment: what JWT library should I import into my PHP login file

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a JWT from your PHP backend and save it in the application (in memory or SessionStorage or LocalStorage).
2. Create a CanActivate implementation that checks the presence of the JWT. If it doesn't find it, it re-routes user to a login page. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards
3. When user clicks a logout button, remove the JWT.

Comment: How to let PHP generate a JWT ? What Library should I use and import ino my php login file ?